# how to print the CMD1,PID,PPID,USER,UID,GID for specific username and it should on same format , I have use this command but it show for all users

Tags: linux, shell, sh

ps -u student -eo "%c %p %P %U"

Answer (score 1):

The command you're looking for is

```
ps -u student -o cmd,pid,ppid,user,uid,gid
```

Answer (score 0):

pop a grep on the command?

```
    ps -u student -eo "%c %p %P %U" | grep student
```

Comment: but how to add , UID ,GID also

Comment: It would be highly recommended to add some explanations of the code you have posted. Simply providing sample code is not the best method to learning programming, and will not benefit the post creator as much as it would if how  and why the code was explained. A well-detailed answer will establish your credibility in the community, and your answers will attract up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

Gottcha!  Missed that part.  I've found 'ps' to be kinda picky.  Separate each output option you want to see by a comma (no spaces).  Like so:

```
    ps -u student -e -o user,command,pid,ppid,gid | grep student
```

You can choose the display order by where in the argument list

You can also put each output option behind its own '-o' (sometimes that's easier to do in an interactive script).